# Smooth Linux VM (VirtualBox) on Windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, unity

I need to create a Virtual Machine running a Linux-based OS. I have tried with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS. The problem that I can't help having is that its interface is laggy and slow in terms of its response, and it is obvious that it's due to a low video performance. A simple example: if I play a 720p video on YouTube, Firefox might crash or the image of the video usually stays frozen.

I have done a little research and the problem is, apparently, how the VM virtualises the graphic resources of my computer, since it doesn't have a video-card. However, my host computer with Windows 10 works just fine, without any troubles. I have also installed the VM in another laptop of mine, which comes with a graphic board, and the difference in performance is remarkably better.

**Hardware specs:**

- i5-5200 @ 2.20GHz 2.19GHz
- 8GB RAM (7.88 to be used)
- Intel HD Graphics 5500
- 250GB SSD

**Virtual Machine specs:**

- 4000MB RAM
- 128MB for video 3D acceleration enabled
- 30GB for storage

I have read that common problems are not having installed VirtualBox Guest Additions or not having enabled Unity 3D, but I have none of them:

[image: Unity 3D is enabled]

[image: VBox Guest Additions is working]

My questions would be:

1. Is there anything that I'm missing or could do in order to improve the performance of the virtual machine?
2. Is there any Linux-based OS which would be more suitable for my computer instead of Ubuntu?

Please, let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Update: I couldn't do anything in order to solve this problem. I have even tried increasing the VRAM to 256 MB through bash-hardcoding, but it didn't help even though. I have finally changed to VMWare Workstation 15, which runs just perfectly, but is not fully free.